# Flashing dots on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I don't see why this code isn't working. It should just draw a white rectangle covering the screen. Then a randomly placed blue dot and wait for the loop to complete. And then repeat the cycle by drawing the white rectangle again and turning off the dot and then redrawing it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Peripheral vision checker</title>


  <script type="application/javascript">

    function draw() {
      // draw crosshairs


      var onFor = 1000;
      const intervalID = setInterval(mytimer, onFor);

      function mytimer()
      {
      // draw white rects

      function getRandomInt(max) {
              return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
              }

      var x = 1280;//will be equal to window height
      var y = 720;//will be equal to window width

      const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.fillStyle = 'white';

      var xcoor =getRandomInt(x);
      var ycoor =getRandomInt(y);

      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, x, y);

        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';

        var radius = 10;
        moveTo(xcoor,ycoor);
        ctx.arc(xcoor, ycoor, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

        //console.log(xcoor + ' ' + ycoor);//just temporary, to see they work
        ctx.fill();
    }

  }

  </script>
 </head>
 <h1>Peripheral vision checker</h1>
 <body onload="draw();">
   <canvas id="canvas" width="1280" height="720"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `beginPath` then `closePath`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Peripheral vision checker</title>


  <script type="application/javascript">
    function draw() {
      // draw crosshairs


      var onFor = 1000;
      const intervalID = setInterval(mytimer, onFor);

      function mytimer() {
        // draw white rects

        function getRandomInt(max) {
          return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
        }

        var x = 500; //will be equal to window height
        var y = 250; //will be equal to window width

        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';

        var xcoor = getRandomInt(x);
        var ycoor = getRandomInt(y);

        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, x, y);

        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';

        var radius = 10;
        ctx.beginPath();
        moveTo(xcoor, ycoor);
        ctx.arc(xcoor, ycoor, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

        //console.log(xcoor + ' ' + ycoor);//just temporary, to see they work
        ctx.fill();

        // no need to: 
        // ctx.closePath();
      }

    }
  </script>
</head>
<h1>Peripheral vision checker</h1>

<body onload="draw();">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does beginPath() always need a closePath()? I thought fill() or stroke() was equivalent of just draw it.

Comment: It seems like a good practice to close it after you open.

Comment: No closePath has no relation with beginPath. This is not a good practice at all; it's at best confusing. closePath will just enclose the current subpath, I.e it will lineTo the last moveTo coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Indeed the names suggest they are not related (begin vs close)

Comment: I agree the naming can be confusing, but that would have been open+close or begin+end if these were going in a pair.